# How a metric computed with cross_val_score can differ from the same metric computed starting from cross_val_predict?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics, cross-validation

How a metric computed with cross_val_score can differ from the same metric computed starting from cross_val_predict (used to obtain predictions to be then given to a metric function)?

Here is an example:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB


iris = datasets.load_iris()

gnb_clf = GaussianNB()
#  compute mean accuracy with cross_val_predict
predicted = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(gnb_clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
accuracy_cvp = metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target, predicted)
#  compute mean accuracy with cross_val_score
score_cvs = cross_validation.cross_val_score(gnb_clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=5)
accuracy_cvs = score_cvs.mean()

print('Accuracy cvp: %0.8f\nAccuracy cvs: %0.8f' % (accuracy_cvp, accuracy_cvs))
```

In this case, we obtain the same result:

```
Accuracy cvp: 0.95333333
Accuracy cvs: 0.95333333
```

Nevertheless, this seems not to be always the case, as [on the official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#obtaining-predictions-by-cross-validation) it is written (regarding a result computed using cross_val_predict):

> Note that the result of this computation may be slightly different
>   from those obtained using cross_val_score as the elements are grouped
>   in different ways.

Comment: Please add a minimal example that illustrates this. Without such an example, I'm afraid it will not be possible to answer this.

Comment: @AmiTavory Done. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: no problem. However, you've answered your own question, no? The docs say the groupings might differ. Maybe you should take this part and move it to an answer (it's fine in SO to answer your own question).

Comment: @AmiTavory It's that part that I don't grasp. I've looked at that line many times, and also the source code, but I would like to see a practical example in which the computation of the same metric leads to different results. For instance, I compute the accuracy on a different dataset and this time the results do not coincide. I would like to have an explanation just a bit more exhaustive than that line, that is, with a practical example. Maybe the explanation will be very much simple, but I just want to be sure that I am using the right tools for validating the classifier.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the source code too, and I don't see how they could differ. (FWIW, a promise that things may be different, is not the same as a promise that they will be different.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine following labels and splitting

[010|101|10]

So you have 8 data points, 4 per class and you split it to 3 folds, leading to 2 folds with 3 elements and one with 2. Now let us assume that during cross validation you get following preds

[010|100|00]

thus, your scores are [100%, 67%, 50%], and cross val score (as an average) is around 72%. Now what about accuracy over predictions? You clearly have 6/8 things right, thus 75%. As you can see the scores are different, even thoug they both rely on cross validation. Here, the difference arises because the splits are not exactly the same size, thus this last "50%" is actually lowering total score because it is an avergae over just 2 samples (and the rest are based on 3).

There might be other similar phenomena, in general - it should boil down to the way averaging is computed. Thus - cross val score is an average over averages, which does not have to be an average over cross validation predictions.

Comment: I've tried with the same example I gave in the question, but this time asking for a 7 folds cross validation. Indeed, the results are slightly different, as 150 (total number of instances in the iris dataset) does not divide exactly by 7. Here are the results: Accuracy cvp: 0.95333333
Accuracy cvs: 0.95408163. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to lejlot's answer, another way that you might get slightly different results between cross_val_score and cross_val_predict is when the target classes are not distributed in a way that allows them to be evenly split between folds.

According to the documentation for [cross_val_predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html), if the estimator is a classifier and y is either binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used by default. This may lead to a situation where even though the total number of instances in the dataset is divisible by the number of folds, you end up with folds of slightly different sizes, because the splitter is splitting based on the presence of the target. This can then lead to the issue where an average of averages is slightly different to an overall average.

For example, if you have 100 data points, and 33 of these are the target class, then `KFold` with `n_splits=5` would split this into 5 folds of 20 observations, but `StratifiedKFold` would not necessarily give you equally-sized folds.