# MachineLearning cross_val_score vs cross_val_predict

Tags: python, validation, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scoring

While building a generic evaluation tool, I came upon the following problem, where the cross_val_score.mean() gives slightly different results than cross_val_predict.

For calculating the testing score I have the following code, which is calculating the score for each fold and then the mean of all.

```
testing_score = cross_val_score(clas_model, algo_features, algo_featurest, cv=folds).mean()
```

For calculating the tp, fp, tn, fn I have the following code, which is calculating these metrics for all folds (i suppose the sum).

```
test_clas_predictions = cross_val_predict(clas_model, algo_features, algo_featurest, cv=folds)
test_cm = confusion_matrix(algo_featurest, test_clas_predictions)
test_tp = test_cm[1][1]
test_fp = test_cm[0][1]
test_tn = test_cm[0][0]
test_fn = test_cm[1][0]
```

The outcome of this code is:

```
                         algo      test  test_tp  test_fp  test_tn  test_fn
5                  GaussianNB  0.719762       25       13      190       71
4          LogisticRegression  0.716429       24       13      190       72
2      DecisionTreeClassifier  0.702381       38       33      170       58
0  GradientBoostingClassifier  0.682619       37       36      167       59
3        KNeighborsClassifier  0.679048       36       36      167       60
1      RandomForestClassifier  0.675952       40       43      160       56
```

So picking the first line cross_val_score.mean() gave 0.719762 (test) and by calculating the score 25+190/25+13+190+71=0.719063545150... ((tp+tn)/(tp+tn+fp+fn)) which are slighty different.

I had the chance to read this from an article in quora: "In cross_val_predict() elements are grouped slightly different than in cross_val_score(). It means that when you will calculate the same metric using these functions, you can get different results."

Is there any particular reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also called out in the documentation for `cross_val_predict`:

> Passing these predictions into an evaluation metric may not be a valid way to measure generalization performance. Results can differ from `cross_validate` and `cross_val_score` unless all tests sets have equal size and the metric decomposes over samples.

It looks like in your case your metric is accuracy, which *does* decompose over samples.  But it is possible (actually likely, because the total size is a not-highly-divisible 299) that your test folds are not of the same size, which could explain the very small (relative) difference in the two.

Comment: What do you mean that the folds may have not same size? The samples are the same in both and also the folds parameter is set to 20.

Comment: And 299/20 is not an integer.  So most folds will have size 15, but one will have size just 14 (and that's assuming your cv-object doesn't try to balance the target classes and violate the equal-size protection more).

Comment: Hmm this looks interesting, now I fully understand what you mean. Thanks a lot Ben!

Comment: I added one more sample to the dataset for the check, and now both are exactly the same. So the problem is the computation of the accuracy of each fold and then the mean() while in the other is the sum of the confusion matrix and then the accurancy.

Answer (score 0):

@bmreiniger, of the many of the posts asking questions about `cross_val_predict`, e.g., [How a metric computed with cross_val_score can differ from the same metric computed starting from cross_val_predict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35318535/4241746), there is a general misunderstanding about what it does.  Or more precisely, what it does not do.  `cross_val_predict` **does not** return scores, it returns the out-of-sample predictions made during the cross-validation process.  By combining these predictions with the true values, *decomposed over the **folds***, the model score of each fold can calculated, which is what `cross_val_score` does.

Each fold has a set of samples used to train a model over that fold and set a test set of samples used to make predictions with this model.  Once these predictions are in hand, they are combined with the true value of the test set, to score that fold's model.

All `cross_val_predict` does is create a model for a given fold with the training set for that fold, then it makes the predictions with the test set of that fold. Finally, it just stacks the predictions over all the folds and returns this stack of predications, ordered by fold.

The result of `cross_val_predict` can quite useful in many applications, e.g., graphing cross-validation results, [Bootstrap Bias Corrected Cross-Validation](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30393425/), and, if properly calculated, a model score.  The assumption is that `cross_val_predict` is used for scoring models.  This is only true if its result is properly post-precessed!

For more details see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77851344/4241746

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77847608/4241746